# Will there be commands in mcpe 0.8.0?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to know if minecraft pocket edition 0.8.0 will have commands.

Answer (score 3):

No there will not be. The following are the things that will be added to MCPE v0.8.0:

> **Additions:**
>
> 1. Minecarts
> 2. Rails[2]
> 3. Powered Rails (always powered.)[3]
> 4. Redstone (mineable and used to craft, but can't be used as Redstone dust until after 0.9.0) [4]
> 5. New Creative Menu (new creative menu and blocks) [5]
> 6. Probably Vines, different colours of wooden planks, and Redstone Repeaters. (They were tweeted by johan in the formal friday picture of
>      0.8.0. Though even some features are not officially announced but secretly added like half the secret features of 0.7.4. The new
>      Creative menu and blocks to be added in 0.8.0 gives these three a even
>      larger chance to appear in 0.8.0.The new biomass to appear in 0.9.0
>      probably one of the is the jungle,gives even much larger for vines,and
>      if were having jungle trees,so for different wooden planks also have a
>      chance).[6]
>
> **Tweaks:**
>
> 1. Redstone Ore now drops Redstone Dust when mined
> 2. Transparent hotbar[7]
> 3. Fire and lava will now ignite TNT.[8]
> 4. Flint and Steel in Creative Mode [9]
>
> **Bug fixes:**
>
> 1. MCPE-2804: Fire doesn't ignite TNT
> 2. MCPE-347: Moiré pattern on certain blocks
> 3. MCPE-61: Water flows downward next to farmland

With reference to this [Link](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1970124-minecraft-pocket-edition-news-080-update/)

Comment: Then when will there be commands

Comment: I'm afraid that as of right now, there has been no confirmation of what would be released in the next major update.

Answer (score 1):

Although the vanilla version of PE doesn't have commands, there is a 3rd party program that gives access to commands. Its like CraftBukkit, but for Pocket Edition.

Its called [PocketMine](http://www.pocketmine.net/)